# How to evaluate spline derivatives from splprep?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I wish to calculate the curvature of a closed curve in numpy using a B-spline. I want to evaluate the derivatives on the spline representation rather than the data to get a smooth result. However the code below returns an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/Users/jfl/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 1212, in splder
        c = (c[1:-1-k] - c[:-2-k]) * k / dt
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

shell returned 1
```

So I am wondering if I am using the `splder` function correctly...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as intplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)


pts = np.vstack((x,y))
tck, u = intplt.splprep(pts, u=None,k=3, s=0.0, per=1)
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 1000)
x_new, y_new = intplt.splev(u_new, tck, der=0)

tck_der1 = intplt.splder(tck)
tck_der2 = intplt.splder(tck_der1)


xp, yp = intplt.splev(u_new, tck_der1, der=0)
xpp, ypp = intplt.splev(u_new, tck_der2, der=0)



plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,".")
plt.plot(x_new,y_new)

plt.figure()
curvature = np.abs(xp* ypp - yp* xpp) / np.power(xp** 2 + yp** 2, 3 / 2)
plt.plot(u_new,curvature)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splder` only supports scalar splines (interpolating a function `y = f(x)` with `splrep`), not vector splines obtained with `splprep`. In any case, you don't need it: just use the `der` parameter of `splev`:

```
xp, yp = intplt.splev(u_new, tck, der=1)
xpp, ypp = intplt.splev(u_new, tck, der=2)
```

This is not a generic finite-difference evaluation of derivative; `splev` will actually use the spline structure to calculate it, which is what you wanted to do.

I guess you tried the above and were unhappy with the output:

[image: output]

But this is just Matplotlib being funny. The plot window is from +9.998e-1  to +9.998e-1 + 0.0006. In other words, the curvature is nearly constant (1), so matplotlib amplifies inevitable noise coming from interpolation. Just set reasonable plot window, and the problem disappears.

[image: nice]

(Or, use something like `x = 2*np.cos(t)` as your example, to get nice nonconstant curvature.)

Comment: Wow ok I feel pretty stupid, I indeed tried this but failed to notice the axis limits... Anyway its good to know the der method works as intended!